How to create a bash one-liner activating Python virtualenv?
I need to have a one-liner, which activates a Python environment and runs a Python script. None of my attempts worked:
bash --rcfile /opt/venv/bin/activate -ci "echo $VIRTUAL_ENV"

bash -c ". /opt/venv/bin/activate && echo $VIRTUAL_ENV"

However, the regular command line have the expected output:
. /opt/venv/bin/activate && echo $VIRTUAL_ENV && deactivate
/opt/venv

How can bash be activated and run Python script in one line as a bash command line parameter?

This is the way:
sh -c '. /opt/venv/bin/activate && echo $VIRTUAL_ENV && deactivate'
/opt/venv

This must be single quotes, not double quotes
